# How can i use ionic4 component in my Angular6 project, when i use ng serve to run

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have an **Angular 6** project, and it is for web. now I want to use it for mobile, so I `npm install @ionic/angular` and follow the directions for [Ionic Integration](https://ionicframework.com/docs/installation/cdn#angular-ionic-framework).

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    MobileSignInComponent,
    MainComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    SharedModule,
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    RouterModule.forChild(
      mainRoutes
    )
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ],
  providers: []
})
```

import to my module

and in HTML file

```
<ion-toolbar>
  <ion-title>Hello Mobile!</ion-title>
</ion-toolbar>
```

then run ng serve

but I got just 'Hello Mobile!' text. not ionic component [project show img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RFXL.png)

the project has no error and no warming!

so what should I do, or ionic component just can be run 'ionic start' project?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem, the mistake I made was that "IonicModule.forRoot ()" should be imported on AppModule, and in SubModule only need to import IonicModule. By the way, Ionic4 needs Angular6+ version. thanks for everyone